# Select specific element with angular

Tags: html, angular, css-selectors

I'm using a `ngFor` loop to `GET` a number of elements from a server.

---

**Target:** Every element has a **View all** button, that when is pressed I want to display the entire JSON object that has been generated by that element

**Problem:** When I press it, I only get the first element.

---

**Code:**

```
<div class="display" *ngFor="let field of fields" >
    <p>Field name: {{field.name}}</p>
    <p>Crop Type: {{field.Crop}}</p>
    <p>Description: {{field.Description}}</p>
    <button class="view" onclick="document.getElementById('ViewAll').style.display = 'block'">View all</button>

  <div  *ngFor="let field of fields" id="ViewAll">
    <p>ID: {{field.ID}}</p>
    <p>Field name: {{field.name}}</p>
    <p>Crop Type: {{field.Crop}}</p>
    <p>Description: {{field.Description}}</p>
    <p>Others: {{field.others}}</p>
  </div>
```

What is wrong? What have I to change?

Comment: I think on click of viewAll button, you just want to show the name,crop,description in JSON of that particular element ?

Comment: @DurgeshPal exactly.But if i have more then one object i can't show the second one.Example:Let's say i have the folowing JSON file :```[{"name": "Field1","Crop": "CropType","Description": "...","ID": "0"},{"name": "Field2","Crop": "CropType2","Description": "...","ID": "1"}]```.When i press the button on the second generated element i get the first element from JSON

Comment: Use `*ngIf="visible" ` in the below div in which you are showing JSON and assign it true on click of view all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always not recommended to use the **`document`** in Angular template. Because mostly Angular will manage the **`DOM`** with it's own background processes.

You can achieve this with the help of another boolean variable.

```
...

<div class="display" *ngFor="let field of fields" >
    <p>Field name: {{field.name}}</p>
    <p>Crop Type: {{field.Crop}}</p>
    <p>Description: {{field.Description}}</p>
    <button class="view" (click)="viewAllBoolean = true">View all</button>
</div>

<ng-container *ngIf="viewAllBoolean">
  <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
    <p>ID: {{field.ID}}</p>
    <p>Field name: {{field.name}}</p>
    <p>Crop Type: {{field.Crop}}</p>
    <p>Description: {{field.Description}}</p>
    <p>Others: {{field.others}}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>

...
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: It is also not recommended to use `onclick`. You should use `(click)` instead. By the way, what is `<ng-template *ngFor="viewAllBoolean">` supposed to do? I doubt that this is valid template syntax.

Comment: Agree and replaced the `ng-template` tag with `ng-container` for ngIf  to check the boolean flag. (I supposed use ngIf before as well). Thank you for pointed it out. :))

Comment: One more observation: I suggest to remove `id="ViewAll"`. There should not be more than one element with a given `id`, and that `id` is not used anyway.